# How to delete extra record from my sql database and Have only 1 row, 

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

```
RowID          MsgID         UserID
1                5            33   
2                5            12
3                5            21
4                5            33   
5                5            33
```

I have this table which I update in different parts of code,

Here there are three entries for User ID 33 for the MsgID 5. I want to have only one row for userid 33 for the msgid 5. How can I delete the record for user id 33 so that I have only 1 record for 33.

I am using MySql

Comment: First of all if you had used `unique index` on `columns(msg, user)` you wouldn't have this problem now.

Comment: I mean there will be another row with MsgID 6 and userid  33. So how can i have unique index, for each message it creates a msgid and Userid and inserts into this table.

Comment: The idea is that the unique index is on both columns at the same time as a pair. It will allow only one (5,33), only one (6,33), only one (a,b) in the general situation.

Answer (score 1):

Mark, you can add a unique key with IGNORE keyword, e.g. -

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK_table_name (MsgID, UserID);
```

It will create new unique key and remove all duplicates from the table using one command.

More information - [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could for simpliticy create a new table (rename later) and have the columns set to unique, then simply

```
INSERT IGNORE new_table
SELECT *
FROM old_table
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you do "insert" in your code, you should check if there is a row with User ID 33 and MsgID 5 and if there is such a row, you should use it instead of inserting the new one.

Comment: he's asking to delete records, rather than using same thing. best thing is to set a unique key constraint..